# Service on android 8

Tags: java, android, android-service

I have a service that has 4 threads.
2 threads work simultaneously, and the others are needed at any time.

It works well prior to Android 7 but does not work on Android 8 or only a thread work.
What can I do to use every 4 threads?

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: @SapuSeven Socket and serverSocket for send and recive text and file

Comment: I mean actual code. You mentioned that your current code works for Android 7.